Ball's Diagonal Perfect Path in a board
This question sounds ridiculous as it seems.
Setup
Assume there is an m x n checker board (m, n is a natural number). Place a ball in any square on the board (assumes this square has the color C).
Rules

The ball must only move on diagonals (so it stays on the same color wherever it moves)

If the ball hits the side border of the board, it bounces 90 degrees.

If the ball hits the corner of the board, it bounces back to the direction it came from. (The picture assumes the big arrow points to the direction that the ball was coming from)


Now, a perfect path is defined to be the path that the ball passes through every squares that have the color C. A perfect board is defined so that the ball always lands on a perfect path when the ball is in the corner colored C (or in different phrasing, both colors have a perfect path).
Problem
Find all n x n perfect boards. (if there are infinite ones, specify the form m, n has, e.g n = 3k + 2 and m = 3k + 1)
For example, this path would be considered perfect (this 11x12 board is also perfect because the path is just mirrored for the opposite color):

Sorry if my drawings look too bad, I was on fast drawing here.
Any contribution to this puzzle-like problem would be welcome. Please explain your answer and have a reasonable proofs.
Statements

If m and/or n = 2k, then the board is perfect if you can find a perfect path. (The other path is mirrored to the first one)
If m = 2k + 1 and n = 2j + 1, there is no perfect paths. That means there would be no perfect boards for m and n this kind.
For all n x n boards, there is no perfect board (since there are two corners that have the color C and these to corners are opposite from each other, so the ball just bounces between those corners)


What have you tried?  Have you tried some small boards?  Which ones work?  Why don't the others?

To be honest, this question seems to be quite easy for square boards $n \times n$. Just try small values of $n$ to see that. Now, what if a board is rectangular $n\times k$…

So, is it a typo, after all, or did you really mean to ask “Find all $\color{red}n \times n$ perfect boards”? You probably meant “Find all $\color{red}m \times n$ perfect boards”?
